# Selenium rc open only the remote control windows an does not display the second browse

Tags: ruby, selenium-rc

I have selenium server 1.03 runing on Ubuntu 9.10 with FF 3.5.3.

I use the following code :

```
require 'selenium/client'
....
@selenium = Selenium::Client::Driver.new \
  :host => "10.0.215.3",
  :port => 4444,
  :browser => "*firefox",
  :url => "http://www.google.fr/",
  :timeout_in_second => 5
....
....
@selenium.start
@selenium.set_context("testportalresources")
@selenium.open "/"
@selenium.wait_for_page_to_load(5000)
@selenium.click('Images')
@selenium.wait_for_page_to_load(5000)
@selenium.stop
```

On the ubuntu computer, i can see only one firefox windows, and it fails on the open image:

```
requested:
    cmd=click
    1=Images
    sessionId=28a3e5f27aa742c6ae9824be4ccab4e4
```

received:
        "ERROR: Element Images not found"

There is no other error. I can browse google from my ubuntu computer. What am i doing wrong? Where is my second FF windows showing the tested website?